# undefined method `configure' for/ Несовместимость версий в railstutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Всем привет!
Я полный новичок в программировании и в Ruby on Rails в частности.
Начал учить последний по http://railstutorial.ru/ и практически сразу столкнулся с ошибкой.
Версия руби - 2.0.0, как в туториале. Изначально были рельсы 4.2.1 - всё работало.
Затем в туториале нужно заменить Gemfile на следующий:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

(Пробовал и с удалением Gemfile.lock, и без него).

В результате изменения Gemfile ставятся рельсы 4.0.2, но выдаёт такую ошибку:

> first_app/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `configure' for #<FirstApp::Application:0xa788d40> (NoMethodError)

Уже без малого 2 дня с этим вопросом пытаюсь разобраться. Пытался решить способами, указанными в ([такой же теме на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22977051/error-launching-rails-server-undefined-method-configure)), но ничего не получается.
Подозреваю, что это просто несовместимость версий.

Попробовал для эксперимента сделать следующее:

1. проверил текущие версии руби и рельсов: 2.0.0 и 4.2.1 соотв.;
2. сделал гемсет под рельсы 4.0.2:

   ```
   rvm gemset create 402r
   ```
3. переключился на созданный гемсет: rvm use 1.9.3@402r
4. на всякий случай проверил нет ли у меня тут рельсов каких-нибудь (с rvm ещё не идеально разобрался): rails -v. Конечно их не оказалось.
5. поставил рельсы 4.0.2:

   ```
   gem install rails --version 4.0.2
   ```
6. Вроде всё стало без ошибок, НО, при rails -v выдало такое:

   > Could not find proper version of railties (4.2.1) in any of the sources.
   >   Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
7. Если теперь сделать `bundle install`, то ставится версия 4.2.1.

Т.о., предполагаю, что руби 2.0.0 и рельсы 4.0.2 банально несовместимы.

Но прав ли я? Неужели учебник устарел?

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для кусков кода не на JS/HTML/CSS следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа в 4 пробела (Ctrl+K). В случае, если код внутри элемента списка, отступ должен быть двойным (8 пробелов).

Comment: Совместимы. Я самолично с них начинал. Но оригинал уже давно обновлён до более свежих версий и Cloud9 IDE в роли средства разработки. Не уверен, хорошо ли это... Вообще если Bundler не может удовлетворить версии из гемфайла, он грохнется с ошибкой. Так что судя по вопросу, проблема с бандлером.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема известная и довольно [полно описана в англоязычном stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857986/rails-nomethoderror-undefined-method-configure-for-firstapp/25050508#25050508).

Резюмируя:

Синтаксис 4.0.8 (как у Хартла http://railstutorial.ru/) отличен от последующих версий.

1. Компромис: редактирование первой строки файла `~\config\environments\development.rb`, где добавить `Rails.application.configure.do` *вместо* `SampleApp::Application.configure do`.
2. При необходимости использовать Рельсы 4.0.8:

   - Явное указание версии `rails_4.0.8_ new first_app` (*specifying the version of Rails to use surrounded by underscores - используя нижнее подчеркивание для указание версии*)
   - Удаление гемов Рельсов выше 4.0.8 с исправлением зависимостей в каталоге проекта